# Search array for object property then hide first occurence of found object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects that I've created using Javascript.  The objects are map layers and have various properties associated.  Upon creation they are pushed into an array.  Below is a simplified example

```
var activeLayers = [];
var mapLayer1 = new mapLayer();
mapLayer1.name = 'roads';
mapLayer1.class = 'infrastucture';
mapLayer1.type = 'line';
activeLayers.push(mapLayer1);

var mapLayer2 = new mapLayer();
mapLayer2.name = 'cities';
mapLayer2.class = 'infrastucture';
mapLayer2.type = 'point';
activeLayers.push(mapLayer2);

var mapLayer3 = new mapLayer();
mapLayer3.name = 'counties';
mapLayer3.class = 'boundaries';
mapLayer3.type = 'polygon';
activeLayers.push(mapLayer3);

var mapLayer4 = new mapLayer();
mapLayer4.name = 'zoningDistricts';
mapLayer4.class = 'political';
mapLayer4.type = 'polygon';
activeLayers.push(mapLayer4);
```

What I want to do is force my map to not allow more than one layer of type==polygon to be displayed at the same time.  I would like to iterate through the array 'activeLayers' and if type==polygon.length > 1 then I would like to remove the oldest from the map.  Removing a layer from the map is accomplished with a function of

```
mapLayer3.hide();
```

In the above array mapLayer3 is a polygon and was added before mapLayer4 and would be hidden from the map.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var prevPoly = null;
for(var i = 0;i < activeLayers.length;i++){
    if(activeLayers[i].type == 'polygon'){
        if(prevPoly){
           prevPoly.hide();
           break;
        }
        else{
           prevPoly = activeLayers[i];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This works for the example on the OP, but what if there is a third polygon on the array? He wants to "force my map to not allow more than one layer of type==polygon to be displayed at the same time", but this will always exit the loop when the second is polygon is found (and hidden).

Comment: OP mentioned I would like to remove the oldest from the map. I doesn't say that all the map should be removed.

Comment: I've read the question again and you are right about that, my answer was wrong. But I'm not sure if the loop should be broken or not.

Comment: this works well.  what if I have 10 possible layers with type=='polygon' and only want to allow 3 showing at one time?  could i easily modify your above code to accommodate this situation?

Comment: The above code will just look for `polygon` type and if more than 1 is found it will remove the first polygon from the root of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably you should just use an object to store the active layers, using key-value pairs of type to visible map. When you make a map layer visible you set the object property to the map you want to display

```
function activeLayers = {};

function showMapLayer(layer) {
    activeLayers[layer.type] = mapLayer;
}

function hideMapLayer(layer) {
    activeLayers[layer.type] = null;
}
```

And you can then iterate over the visible layers using a for ... in loop

```
var layer;
for (layer in activeLayers)
{
    if (layer && activeLayers.hasOwnProperty(layer)) {
        // this is an active layer, do something with it
    }    
}
```

I do realise this doesn't preserve the order in which you added the layers so you could always keep track of this using the object as a guide. (I will update with an example)